# GDB, new language (Flash AS) port

Tags: debugging, actionscript, gdb

Are there any Flash Action Script (AS) debuggers capable of debugging on a embedded target?

We have a software stack where AS is only a small part of it, larger of the code base is in C. As of now we can only debug C code using GDB.

I could not find any debugger that would suit my requirement.

What would be the quantum of work involved to get AS debugging capability into GDB ?

Thanks and Regards 
Shri -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FlashBuilder debugger is capable of debugging C++ embedded (ActiveX) swf files.  I use it this way every day. I don't see a reason why it or the standalone debugger would not be capable of debugging most any embedded target.

Since the debugger works simply by starting and then listening for a running debug swf all you need to do is start the debugger before the point in your code that loads the embedded swf. (assuming that the swf is a debug swf)  Of course you need to have the linkages set up for the debugger (i.e. in FlashBuilder a corresponding project set up) That is unless you just want trace statements.

The work-flow is different than a normal Flex build but pretty simple. If you use eclipse/FlashBuilder the key is to set the  "URL or path to launch" in the debug configuration to "about:blank"  this will ensure that the builder does not try to open the swf in a browser or the stand alone player.

It will therefore start the debugger and wait.  (You can see it in the eclipse progress panel just waiting.)  You then trigger or start the part of your containing program that loads the embedded content.  If the embedded content is a debug swf it should call out and try to connect to any running debuggers.

I don't use the standalone swf debugger but I think you can do something similar with it.